# Reciprocity failure of Rollei Retro 80S at extreme long times

Tags: film, long-exposure, negative-film

I am planning to do some night shots and wanted to use Retro 80S. But I couldn't find anything on the films reciprocity failure...with a few seconds, doubling the time will probably work, but with measured times of 4 or 8 minutes? For instance with HP5 i would get some 20 minutes...
Does anyone have experience with long time exposures on Retro 80S or have reciprocity table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 4 to 8 minutes -- 2/3 to 1 f-stop compensation is all you need apply.